# django-admin startproject doesn't do anything

Tags: python, django

I use command "django-admin startproject myapp" and it doesn't do anything
When I use this command again it says "CommandError: 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\djangotest2\myapp' already exists"
I tried disabling my antivirus and I tried using absolute path to django-admin.py and django-admin.exe file

Comment: Looks like it did do something if it's created the "myapp" folder. What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @IainShelvington it only says that it already exists, but in fact, it doesn't,
there is no new folder, when I use "mkdir myapp" it creates a folder